# _.groupBy but _.sort first

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I got this array,

I need to group on `id`, but first sort it by `timestamp`

```
sample_array = [
    {id: 21, timestamp:1, year: 2012},
    {id: 11, timestamp:2, year: 2017},
    {id: 12, timestamp:3, year: 2016},
    {id: 11, timestamp:4, year: 2014},
    {id: 11, timestamp:5, year: 2015},
    {id: 19, timestamp:6, year: 2016},
    {id: 12, timestamp:7, year: 2016}
    ]
```

What i try to achieve using `underscore.js` is to sort my array using timestamp first, but then check if exists another entry for same id, then group on it before next id:

expected results :

```
[
    {id: 21, timestamp:1, year: 2012},
    {id: 11, timestamp:2, year: 2017},
    {id: 11, timestamp:4, year: 2014},
    {id: 11, timestamp:5, year: 2015},
    {id: 12, timestamp:3, year: 2016},
    {id: 12, timestamp:7, year: 2016},
    {id: 19, timestamp:6, year: 2016}
]
```

I try to achieve this by using combination of `_.groupBy` and `_.sortBy`.

The need is to :

1. group by id
2. sort by timestamp in each group
3. sort groups by their minimum timestamp (first timestamp in each group)

Comment: Please, show the code, how you've tried already. Also which property should be used for sorting, and which for grouping?

Comment: As per the description i think `timestamp:6` should be before `timestamp:7` in your expected result

Comment: @Avinash no, `timestamp:6` is linked to `id: 13`. This id is after `id: 12`. Expected results is correct

Comment: expected results show no groupping. I see just sorting by id first and by timestamp next.

Comment: @ischenkodv first sort by timestamp. If exists same `id`, then next is same `id` with an older `timestamp`

Comment: @skyboyer the first sort is related to `timestamp`

Comment: if "first sort is related to timestamp" why do you have `timestamp: 4` before `timestamp: 3` but after `timestamp: 1` in expected results?

Comment: @skyboyer because I need first to get the lowest `timestamp` first, then if exits any related `id` (replicated id), then next result has to be the next `timestamp` of this replicated `id`

Comment: group by id, sort by timestamp in each group then sort groups by their minimum timestamp(first timestamp in each group actually) and flatten groups into flat list. is it what you want?

Comment: @skyboyer sounds good

Comment: Create an object that maps each ID to its lowest timestamp. Then sort the original array first by this mapping, then by timestamp.

Comment: You should update the question to include all this clarification of the problem, rather than leaving it in comments.

Comment: @Barmar done, I hope it will be enough for next readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on next understanding:

> group by id, sort by timestamp in each group then sort groups by their minimum timestamp(first timestamp in each group actually) and flatten groups into flat list.

```
_.chain(sample_array)
 .groupBy('id')
 .mapObject(groupPerId=> _.sortBy(groupPerId, 'timestamp'))
 .sortBy(groupPerId=> groupPerId[0].timestamp)
 .flatten()
 .value()
```

Comment: I try to understand how works `.mapObject(groupPerId=> _.sortBy(groupPerId, 'timestamp'))`

Comment: it sorts items inside of group per id; `.mapObject` actually the same as `.map` but latest would convert object into array that would create a mess

Comment: @Toucouleur check Nina Scholz's answer. I believe it's a better solution(2*N while mine solution is 3*N). Could you accept her answer instead?

Answer (score 2):

You could sort by `timestamp` and then sort by `id`, but do not take the number, because numbers are sorted to top in objects. Therefore you need to convert the number to a string and group by it.

Then map the values and flatten the arrays.

```js
var array = [{ id: 21, timestamp:1, year: 2012 }, { id: 11, timestamp:2, year: 2017 }, { id: 12, timestamp:3, year: 2016 }, { id: 11, timestamp:4, year: 2014 }, { id: 11, timestamp:5, year: 2015 }, { id: 13, timestamp:6, year: 2016 }, { id: 12, timestamp:7, year: 2016 }],
    result = _.chain(array)
        .sortBy(['timestamp'])
        .groupBy(o => _ + o.id)
        .map(v => v)
        .flatten()
        .value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Script error.`but I understand the way you deal with it

Comment: @Toucouleur ignore an error. just scroll output to the top and you will see output

Comment: When I run your code, I got ```{
_chain:
true
_wrapped:
(7)[
{
id:
10
timestamp:
1
year:
2012
}, [...]```
how can i get the result directly ?

Comment: I did it but not better

Comment: i added a mapping and then flatten and then values. please try this.

Comment: What mean `.groupBy(o => _ + o.id)`

Comment: it means it changes the timestamp, which is a number to a defined string, wich keep the order in an object. if taking a number, which is a 32 bit positive integer, then this key is in an object sorted by value, which destroys the previous order. the underscore prevents from sorting (you could use any other character or pre- or postfix).

Answer (score 0):

If this array is the problem, you can solve simply as follows, you can play with digits if zeros adding to timestamp, an taking the exact number for each timestamp :), check it should work (this example is maximum 5 digits of timestamp) if it has more you can add zeros at beginings

```
    sample_array.sort(function(a,b){
return Number(a.id.toString()+('00000'+a.timestamp.toString()).substr(a.timestamp.toString().length-1))-Number(b.id.toString()+('00000'+b.timestamp.toString()).substr(b.timestamp.toString().length-1))
})
```

Comment: This won't work if timestamps have different numbers of digits. `id 1 timestamp 20` will sort after `id 2 timestamp 5`.